# A table with some cells selected

Tags: tables

I have an assignment at university and I have to write some documents written by hand into a TeX document. I'm facing a problem with the following table:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve a result similar to the picture above using TeX? I'm not asking for a provided working solution, I'm wondering if I should do it with a photo editor or not (and in this case a little hint would be helpful).

Comment: Examples for cell highlighting can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/highlighting-table-cells), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94799/how-do-i-color-table-columns-and-rows) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67313/highlight-table-cells-using-thick-colored-border). [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132818/31323) shows an example for the beamer class, but looks more like what you want.

Comment: Maybe even better: [Circle around content of a table: is it possible?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35881/circle-around-content-of-a-table-is-it-possible)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, some examples in the links provide the code I need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `tikz` package and put your table (I use the simple `tableau` package here) inside a node to make drawing easier. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ytableau,tikz,varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\begin{document}

\ytableausetup{boxsize=2em}
\begin{tikzpicture}[b/.style={rounded corners,fill=blue!50,opacity=0.5,minimum width=1.2em,minimum height=7.5em}]
\node (n) {\begin{varwidth}{5cm}{
\begin{ytableau}
50 & 0 & 150 & 200 \\
50 & 0 & 200 & 100 \\
100 & 0 & 250 & 200 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{ytableau}}\end{varwidth}};

\node [b] at ([xshift=-1em]n) {};
\node [b,rotate=90] at ([yshift=-3em]n) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The table now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Only with `tikz` and the `fit` and `matrix` libraries. I also used `backgrounds` library for *highlighting* in the *background* (and does not cover the numbers).

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,% Not strictly necessary but useful to put math symbols $...$
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,% Overlaps borders of the nodes 
nodes={draw,minimum width=2em,minimum height=2em},inner sep=0.5ex] (mymatrix) {
    50  & 0 & 150 & 200 \\
    50  & 0 & 200 & 100 \\
    100 & 0 & 250 & 200 \\
     0  & 0 &  0  &  0  \\
};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[fill=blue!50,opacity=0.5,inner sep=-0.8ex,rounded corners=6pt,fit=(mymatrix-1-2)(mymatrix-4-2)] {};
\node[fill=blue!50,opacity=0.5,inner sep=-1ex,rounded corners=6pt,fit=(mymatrix-4-1)(mymatrix-4-4)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]