# Two minipages with 0.5\textwidth each get placed one below another

Tags: beamer, positioning, minipage

This happens in the `beamer` class only. Does anyone know the reason behind this? I fix it by just setting both widths to `0.49\textwidth` and this works but I'm still curious why this happens and if I maybe do something wrong.

MWE here:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
asdfasdf
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
asdfasdf
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wrote that already :) But I'm more interested in why this happens and if there is a mistake on my end (misusing the minipage environment e.g.). Also I copy pasted a sligthly altered version of the MWE at first where one width was .5 and the other .49. I'm wondering why .5+0.5 doesn't give me two minipages next to eachother.

Comment: Ah, sorry for not understanding this point right away. As far as I can tell, you're not making a mistake.

Comment: Beamer provides a `columns` environment that allows to place things next to each other. It might be a cleaner solution for you (see beamer documentation for details).

Comment: Didn't know about columns but they indeed are a better solution.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a space between the two minipages so the total of the line is more than `\textwidth`. Add a `%` directly after the first `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: nice, thanks! What does the `%` do? I assume removing spaces but maybe you can give me an accurate answer? TeXshop also includes a `%` when inserting a table via menu.

Comment: `%` is the standard TeX comment character. It gobbles up anything until the end of the line (including the line end which is normally turned into a space). If that is not known to you I suggest you read some intro document on LaTeX as then you are probably missing a lot useful information. Try `lshort.pdf` for example or any of its translation into some language.

Comment: by the way ... therefore never ever write something like "so 20% of xyz..." because then half of your sentence will be missing in the output.

Comment: I knew that `%` is used for commenting but I didn't know that you could use it for changing the layout as well, which it really does in this case. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't change the layout, it drops the line end character as part of the commenting so you have one space less and that was the offending one in your example.

Comment: @Philipp: Have a look at [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946)