# Aligning a minipage in the absolute top left

Tags: margins, geometry, covers

I'm formatting a cover design in LaTeX. The cover has pages of 145×210mm which includes 3mm margin. The side should be 13.93mm wide and the bleed is 3mm. This gives me the following code, which declares three minipages: one for the back of the book, one for the side, and one for the front.

```
\documentclass[paper=303.93mm:210mm,10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[center,cross,width=309.93mm,height=216mm]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}%
\begin{minipage}{145mm}
\lipsum[0-5]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{13.93mm}
Blah blah blah
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{145mm}
\lipsum[7-11]
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

However, the first minipage is not aligned in the absolute top left, but a little bit to the right, so that the rightmost minipage ends up in the bleed area:

[image]

As you can see I already removed extra spaces inbetween as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54103/23992), but that didn't resolve the issue. I also already set the margins to 0 with geometry.

How can I align the minipage in the absolute top?

Comment: Adding `\noindent` before `\begin{minipage}`?

Comment: @egreg _right_, of course. I didn't think of it, that it would apply to minipages as well, but of course it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're doing a cover page, it's better to set

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

before `\begin{document}`. Note that `\parindent` is set to zero inside a `minipage` anyway, but this doesn't affect normal paragraphing.

As far as TeX is concerned, you're just making a paragraph and a minipage is nothing more than a “big” character to TeX's eyes.

Or just add `\noindent` before the starting `\begin{minipage}`.