# TeX complains about a "Package inputenc Error"

Tags: errors, input-encodings

Compiling a simple document, I get the following error:

[image: (Tex error image)]

On the line 166, there is a `\begin{itemize}` environment. I tried commenting it out and the error goes away, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that part of code. I'm posting it below (from line 164 to 169):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[Presuposiciones] Son aseveraciones no expresadas. Son supuestos que el hablante hace 
sobre lo que probablemente aceptará al oyente sin ponerlo en duda. 
Para que un texto sea coherente que el emisor haya acertado en sus presuposiciones.
\item[Implicaturas] Se relacionan estrechamente con los actos de habla indirectos.
Se trata de las informaciones adicionales contenidas en un enunciado. 

\end{itemize}

\end{document
```

What's happening?

Comment: check your input encoding , it should be utf-8 as there are some utf characters in your latex file

Comment: @texlearner But the rest of the document loads fine. That's why it's weird. I mean, I have characters with accents everywhere.

Comment: I have added a minimal working example (I suppose it should work).

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine for me. Did you save the file with other encoding than the utf, this error would occur

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great... I thought it could be something like that! ARGH.

Comment: Look at the log file with `hexdump` and search for `\u8:`; what are the two bytes following it?

Comment: @egreg A tab space (or what it's called). But I made sure to delete it earlier, perhaps my search wasn't very good. :)

Comment: @egreg Ah got it. It was before "Para", in the first \item.

Comment: @egreg How not to end up with this type of problem ? Any suggestion

Comment: @texlearner Just explore the line where Tex complains I suppose. :D

Comment: @texlearner Use a good editor. The character might have been a "NO-BREAK SPACE" (U+00A0) and it may be difficult to spot. On Emacs it's shown by a thin underscore.

Comment: @egreg is that the reason sometimes people use % characters at the line endings ?

Comment: @texlearner: See [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a control character after the full stop after `duda.` If you delete that then it all seems to work.

Comment: Yes I found it. :) I should have checked better!

Comment: The '\u8' in the error message might be the clue to this, on another occasion - a backspace crept in, somehow?