# How can I remove the blank space before and after a command

Tags: macros, spacing

I create a command,

```
\newcommand{\cmd}{b}
```

but when I use this command

```
a\cmd{}c
```

What I get is

> a b c

but what I want is

> abc

How can I remove two blanks?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With that definition and usage you'll get the second instance, not the first. Probably you should show your *real* case.

Comment: A complete code is necessary because like egreg wrote, you should show your real case. Perhaps you want `a b c` ?

Comment: if you *never* want a space before or after the contents of the command, define it as  \newcommand{\cmd}{\unskip b\ignorespaces}.

Comment: If there are line breaks in your actual command definition, you need to add comment signs, see [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946).

Comment: You sure your definition does not contain spaces as in `\newcommand{\cmd}{ b }`. This would yield the result that you describe that you are getting.

Comment: My environment is Ctex, a chinese latex version.