# Raisebox appears to inset 4pt of space to left of object raised?

Tags: spacing

So, I have been working on writing a package for typesetting "[fregean Begriffsschrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift)". While working on the universal quantifier, I tried raising the semi circular depression in the content stroke, made in a picture environment using the \raisebox command. This has worked fine with respect to raising the picture to the hight I want, but it also inserted 4pt. worth of white space to the left of my picture environment, creating a gap I don't want. I found it possible to get rid of this unwanted space using \kern, however I would like to know exactly why the white space appears.

```
\newlength{\temp}
\newlength{\Fbaselength}
\setlength{\Fbaselength}{10pt}
\newlength{\Flinewidth}
\setlength{\Flinewidth}{0.5pt}
\newlength{\Fspace}
\setlength{\Fspace}{2pt}
\newlength{\Fraisehight}
\setlength{\Fraisehight}{1ex}
\addtolength{\Fraisehight}{-\Flinewidth}
\newlength{\Fnegsep}
\setlength{\Fnegsep}{3\Flinewidth}
\newlength{\Fnegshort}
\setlength{\Fnegshort}{2\Flinewidth}
\newlength{\Fquantwidth}
\setlength{\Fquantwidth}{6pt}


%%% twice negated universal quantifier
\newcommand{\Fnnquant}[1]
{
  \unskip
  \setlength{\temp}{\Fbaselength}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-0.5\Fquantwidth}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-2\Flinewidth}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-\Fnegsep}
  \rule[\Fraisehight]{0.5\temp}{\Flinewidth}
  \setlength{\temp}{\Fraisehight}
  \addtolength{\temp}{\Flinewidth}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-\Fnegshort}
  \rule[\Fnegshort]{\Flinewidth}{\temp}
  \rule[\Fraisehight]{\Fnegsep}{\Flinewidth}
  \setlength{\temp}{\Fraisehight}
  \addtolength{\temp}{\Flinewidth}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-\Fnegshort}
  \rule[\Fnegshort]{\Flinewidth}{\temp}
  \setlength{\temp}{\Fbaselength}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-0.5\Fquantwidth}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-2\Flinewidth}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-\Fnegsep}
  \rule[\Fraisehight]{0.5\temp}{\Flinewidth}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\Fquantwidth}
  % \kern-4pt
  \raisebox{\Fraisehight}{
  \begin{picture}(1,0)(0,0)
    \linethickness{\Flinewidth}
    \qbezier(0,0)(0.5,-0.6666)(1,0)
  \end{picture}}
  %% \kern-\Fquantwidth
  %% \setlength{\temp}{0.5\Fquantwidth}
  %% \addtolength{\temp}{-0.45ex} 
  %% \vbox{\hbox to \Fquantwidth{\hskip\temp\ensuremath{^#1}}\vskip0.2\Fraisehight}
  \setlength{\temp}{\Fbaselength}
  \addtolength{\temp}{-0.5\Fquantwidth}
  \rule[\Fraisehight]{\temp}{\Flinewidth}
  \hskip\Fspace
}
```

The relevant bit of the code is that between the two sections that have been commented out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! An example of usage would be best. However you have many spaces (in the form of newline characters) in the definition of `\Fnnquant`. In particular there should be a `%` just after the final `{` in the `\raisebox` line.

Comment: See [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing % at the ends of lines so getting spaces in your output.

```
\newcommand{\Fnnquant}[1]
{%%%%%%
  \unskip
  \setlength{\temp}{\Fbaselength}%%%%%%
  \addtolength{\temp}{-0.5\Fquantwidth}%%%%%%
  \addtolength{\temp}{-2\Flinewidth}%%%%%%
  \addtolength{\temp}{-\Fnegsep}%%%%%%
  \rule[\Fraisehight]{0.5\temp}{\Flinewidth}%%%%%%
  \setlength{\temp}{\Fraisehight}%%%%%%
```

etc etc

Comment: Well, one `%` per line is enough ;-) Further details: [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946)

Comment: Sometimes things can be so simple. Thanks for the quick replies. There goes my first vaguely embarrassing newbie question. I am sure there will be more to follow.

Comment: @Psachnodaimonia You could make your introduction complete by accepting the answer which was most helpful to you.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Done! Still finding my way about Stack Exchange.