# How do I define tikz styles with a xkeyval command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, xkeyval

I would like to write a command which allows the user to change tikz styles. My code goes like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\def\DEFstyle{}
\define@key{styles}{styleA}{\def\DEFstyle{#1}}
\newcommand{\setstyles}[1]{%
  \setkeys{styles}{styleA={}} 
  \setkeys{styles}{#1}
  \tikzstyle{TIKZSTYLE}=[\DEFstyle]
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setstyles{styleA={top color=green,bottom color=red}}
\end{document}
```

However, I always get an error message:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/top
>   color=green,bottom color=red' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you
>   misspelled it.

But the content of `\DEFstyle` is definitely `top color=green,bottom color=red` and when I directly write `\tikzstyle{TIKZSTYLE}=[top color=green,bottom color=red]` then everything works fine. Where does the bug hide?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: The exact option is not important as long as it works. `\tikzset{TIKZSTYLE/.style/.expand once=\DEFstyle}` seems to work! Thanks a lot! May you consider to explain your solution? Otherwise I can answer this question myself. Also: thanks for the link.

Comment: I cant answer my own question yet due to stackexchange spam limits.

Answer (score 6):

First of all,

```
\tikzstyle{<key>}=[<value>]
```

is the same as

```
\tikzset{<key>/.style={<value>}}
```

From this point I will only use the `\tikzset` syntax (→ [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)). But you would've had the same problem with `\tikzset`.

The assignment is not a problem, the style `TIKZStyle` contains simply your argment to `styleA`. But when TikZ executes this style (say when `\draw[TIKZSTYLE]`) it sees firstly `\DEFstyle` and its definition and tries it as a key, but a key named `top color=green,bottom color=red` (for TikZ this is just one “string” at this moment) does not exist.

Even `top color=green` won’t work because, again, TikZ does not see the `=` hidden in `\DEFstyle`.
The only thing that would work is is a style without a parameter, say

```
\setstyles{styleA={rounded corners}}%
\tikz \draw[TIKZSTYLE] (0,0) rectangle (1em,2ex);
```

which results in [image: rounded rectangle]. But even that is not safe enough:

```
\setstyles{styleA={rounded corners}}%
\def\DEFstyle{fill}%
\tikz \draw[TIKZSTYLE] (0,0) rectangle (1em,2ex);
```

(But then again, throw some `@` in the `\DEFstyle` macro’s name …).

These are the reasons we need to expand `\DEFstyle` before assigning it to the `TIKZSTYLE` style:

```
\tikzset{TIKZSTYLE/.style/.expand once=\DEFstyle}%
```

In your definition of the `\setstyles` macro are some spurious spaces:

- [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/16595)
- [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946/16595)
- and the dozens of linked questions …

---

I do not know much about your project, but as a reminder, you can do this all with PGF keys. See the second Code block.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\def\DEFstyle{}
\define@key{styles}{styleA}{\def\DEFstyle{#1}}
\newcommand{\setstyles}[1]{%
  \setkeys{styles}{styleA={}}%
  \setkeys{styles}{#1}%
  \tikzset{TIKZSTYLE/.style/.expand once=\DEFstyle}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setstyles{styleA={top color=green,bottom color=red}}
\tikz \draw[TIKZSTYLE] (0,0) rectangle (1em,2ex);
\end{document}
```

### Code (sans-`xkeyval`)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\pgfkeys{
    /no xkeyval/styleA/.style={
        /tikz/TIKZSTYLE/.style={#1}
    }
}
\newcommand*{\setstyles}[1]{%
    \pgfqkeys{/no xkeyval}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}%
\setstyles{styleA={top color=green,bottom color=red}}%
\tikz \draw[TIKZSTYLE] (0,0) rectangle (1em,2ex);
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One use of *xkeyval* package might be to preset some keys, so that their preset values can be used when no user value is provided for them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{styles}{color set}{\def\rectstyle{#1}}
\define@key{styles}{rect size}{\def\rectsize{#1}}
\presetkeys{styles}{color set={top color=white,bottom color=gray},rect size={5em,5em}}{}
\newcommand*{\setstyles}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{styles}{#1}%
  \edef\tempa{\unexpanded{\tikz\draw}[\rectstyle](0,0)rectangle(\rectsize)}\tempa;
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setstyles
\hspace{1cm}
\setstyles[color set={top color=green,bottom color=red},rect size={5ex,6ex}]
\hspace{1cm}
\setstyles[rect size={10ex,8ex}]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]