# Expanding macro defined by \csdef to define a style via \tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, expansion, etoolbox

I need to store `tikz` option in a `\csdef{}`:

```
\csdef{My Node Option}{draw=red, thick, fill=yellow}
```

How do I use this definition to define a style via `\tikzset`?
I attempted to use `.expand once` as per [How do I define tikz styles with a xkeyval command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101052/4301):

```
\tikzset{Node Options/.style/.expand once=\csuse{My Node Option}}
```

but that leads to a

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/draw=red, thick, fill=yellow' and I am going to ignore it.  Perhaps you misspelled it.

The desired result is to modify *only* the `\tikzset` in the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) and obtain:

[image]

### Notes:

- As egreg commented, spaces in names of commands should be avoided. However, in my actual use case, the command names defined by the `csdef{}` are named after file names with paths which include spaces, slashes, numbers, periods.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}


\csdef{My Node Option}{draw=red, thick, fill=yellow}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{Node Options/.style/.expand once=\csuse{My Node Option}}%% ????

    \node [Node Options] at (0,0) {Node Text};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You'd need `/.expand thrice`, which doesn't exist. But `/.expand twice=\csname My Node Option\endcsname` works. I *know* that spaces in names of commands and options is bad. `;-)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `expanded` instead of `expand once` in your MWE:

`\tikzset{Node Options/.style/.expanded=\csuse{My Node Option}}%% ????`

Comment: +1 It's better to give a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) as an answer to  show that your solution works, but I agree that this does work and hence that this is probably the preferred tikz solution.

Answer (score 8):

`\csuse{...}` is not quite the same as `\csname...\endcsname`:

```
% etoolbox.sty, line 883:
\newcommand*{\csuse}[1]{%
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname
    \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
  \fi}
```

If you expand once in your context you get

```
\ifcsname My Node Option\endcsname\csname My Node Option\endcsname\fi
```

A further expansion step will remove the conditional, leaving

```
\csname My Node Option\endcsname\fi
```

which requires *two* expansion steps in order to deliver

```
draw=red, thick, fill=yellow\fi
```

but then the `\fi` kicks in, because it is shuffled around at the wrong place.

You can do

```
\tikzset{Node Options/.style/.expand twice=\csname My Node Option\endcsname}
```

that avoids the problem of the dangling `\if`.

However, the best strategy, in my opinion, is to use styles all around:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{My Node Option/.style={draw=red, thick, fill=yellow}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{Node Options/.style=My Node Option}

\node [Node Options] at (0,0) {Node Text};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup <stuff to expand>}\x` expansion trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\csdef{My Node Option}{draw=red, thick, fill=yellow}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\tikzset{Node Options/.style={\csuse{My Node Option}}}}%
  \x

  \node [Node Options] at (0,0) {Node Text};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Note the additional braces around the `\csuse`.