# Declare new command using another command with a name based on its input?

Tags: macros

I'm trying to write a command that will declare another command with a name that will be based on the input given to the outer command: e.g.

```
\newcommand{\buildcommand}[1]{
  \newcommand{\someprefix#1}{do stuff}
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as I keep getting errors. How should I go about getting this to work?

Comment: you need to build the csname first: `\newcommand{\buildcommand}[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname someprefix#1\endcsname{do stuff}}`

Comment: @cgnieder why not turning your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to build the name of the command sequence first before you can define the command with `\newcommand`. This is done with `\csname <macro name without leading backslash>\endcsname`. Since `\csname` needs to be expanded *before* `\newcommand` (you don't want to define `\csname` itself) an `\expandafter` is needed:

```
\newcommand{\buildcommand}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname someprefix#1\endcsname{do stuff}%
}
```

If you want to keep the braces around the new command name you need to “step over them” with another `\expandafter`:

```
\newcommand{\buildcommand}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname someprefix#1\endcsname}{do stuff}%
}
```

I also added `%` at the end of the first two lines of the definition in order to avoid spurious spaces, see [Why the end-of-line % in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/why-the-end-of-line-in-macro-definitions) and [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines) for further explanation on that.

Comment: I'd mention `\@namedef`.

Comment: @egreg I thought about that but left it out because it hasn't `\newcommand`'s checks... And since it is unclear what the code is supposed to do in the end I was being lazy, anyway...