# Problem Using \hfill to Justify Text

Tags: spacing

I am writing a resume using the scrartcl,currvita, and classicthesis packages. Everything else is fine but I have run into a problem correctly justifying some dates along the right side of the page. When I use the command '\NewEntry', as defined below, it leaves a small white space of about 0.5em at the right side of the page, even though I have used /hfill. If I add the line manually instead of using a function, it does not do this, as shown in the picture. I have attached all of the code that I think is relevant. Can someone explain to me why it is doing this? Obviously I could just hand code it every time or correct it with /hspace(-0.5em) but I would much prefer to use a function.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned, NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[letterpaper,top=0.35in, bottom=0.15in, left=1.5in, right=0.5in,marginparwidth=1in,marginparsep=0.25in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[2]{\raggedright\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \textsc{\bf#1}  {\hfill\small\textit{#2}}
 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here
\vspace{0.15em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\begin{document}


\pdfpageheight 11in 
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

\begin{cv}{}

---------------

\NewEntry{University of the Pacific}{Expected May 2016}

\raggedright\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \textsc{\bf University of the Pacific} \hfill {\small\textit{Expected May 2016}}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please, always post a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) people can compile to reproduce the problem. Much more useful than fragments of code.

Comment: Off-topic: don't use `\bf` - it was deprecated 20+ years ago. More on topic: usually, you would use `\raggedleft` or the `flushright` environment (from `ragged2e`?) to set text right, rather than forcing it with `\hfill`.

Comment: Your curly brackets in your macro definition don't add up. You have 4 left and 3 right. Probably the last one is after a line break which will insert a space. But, really, without an MWE, it is all guesswork.

Comment: Ok. I just edited the post to include a working example. Thanks for the advice on \bf.

Comment: You have `{\hfill\small\textit{#2}} `, which is adding space at the end of the line; change it to `{\hfill\small\textit{#2}}%`.  (This is surely a duplicate of some more general question. [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946/8528) seems to link to several.)

Comment: Thank you Jon, that fixed it. Is there a reason it is necessary in the function and not when it is just written out?

Comment: Yes: In the 'manual' version, the series of commands is immediately closed by the second brace (i.e., the `}`) so there's no space in the input.  In your macro, however, you have `{\hfill\small\textit{#2}}˽\vspace{0.15em}` (where the `˽` marks an explicit space in the macro definition).  So in your definition, you are (accidentally) asking for a space before your `\vspace` command, while in the 'manual' version you are not.  Hopefully, the linked-to question (and answers) above provide more detail.

Comment: Off-topic, but you should also consider switching from "TeX" font-switching commands to "LaTeX" ones (e.g., from `\bf` to `\bfseries`).  See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/8528).

Comment: @jon See discussion above ;).

Comment: @cfr -- Hmm, my memory is fading fast!  I did see your comment about the `\bf`, but then forgot about it while 'answering' the main problem (which I figured was justified since there was now an example on display and it was a duplicate question/issue anyway -- even though your suspicion turned out to be correct).