# Put pgfplots axis on the margin of printable text area

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning

In order to gain some horizontal space (e.g. to put two plots next to each other) and because this is the least ugly solution for that I would like to be able to put the axis line of a pgfplot exactly on the border where text would begin (or end) in a line. (in the MWE below: it should lie directly on the frame of the text area). Shifting them manually by trying out appropriate values (as done in the MWE) is not the ideal solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\myfig}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[height=5cm,width=7cm]
    \addplot {2^x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
\myfig % too much space on the left

\hspace{-12.5mm}\myfig % correct (but manual) placement

\flushright
\myfig % too much space on the right

\myfig\hspace*{-3.3mm} % correct (but manual) placement
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

I know I must work with anchors but later I am working in floating environments and cannot give an exact (vertical) position related to the page. Who knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim axis left` and `trim axis right` is what you're looking for. These options can be added to the arguments of the `tikzpicture` (not the `axis`), and changes the bounding box so that everything left (right) of `current axis.south west` (`current axis.south east`) is trimmed away.

Note that in your example I also added some `%` in the `\myfig` macro to avoid spurious spaces (see e.g. [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946)), and I added a `\noindent` to remove the standard paragraph indent.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\myfig}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \begin{axis}[height=5cm,width=7cm]
    \addplot {2^x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

\begin{document}
\noindent\myfig{trim axis left}


\flushright
\myfig{trim axis right}
\end{document}
```

Comment: way easier than I expected, very nice! I know about the % trick and my final document has no indentaion and I didn't care about either of those for my example, but an extra thanks for even thinking about that!