# clearfield ateverycitekey producing spaces

Tags: biblatex

As the title suggests, using this MCVE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{
    \clearfield{location}
    \clearfield{publisher}
}

\begin{filecontents}{the.bib}
    @article{label,
        title = {Best paper ever},
        author = {Best author in universe},
        location = {Earth},
        publisher = {fiend},
        date = {0000},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{the}

\begin{document}
    Why the heck is there a space:\cite{label}?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Produces a space between `:` and the word "Best" from the author field. This space is increased per field cleared. You can verify this space is gone by commenting out the `ATEveryCitekey` command. This also happens for a numeric cite - the square brackets have additional spacing within.

My current fix is to manually `\hspace` the citation backwards, but this has to be done for every citation as they are a bit differently indented depending on the bibliographic content!

How do I get `\clearfield` to stop spacing things?

Comment: Add `%` to the end of lines in `\AtEveryCitekey`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864 for an in-depth explanation why that is necessary (also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946/35864).

Comment: @moewe Correct! how anti-climactic. I should have thought about newlines!

Comment: Sorry, that the solution is not more exciting. ;-) Do we close this as a duplicate or do you want an answer? (Ah, I see Steven was quicker than me...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just added `%` at the end of the `\AtEveryCitekey` lines, to prevent stray spaces from being introduced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \clearfield{location}%
    \clearfield{publisher}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{the.bib}
    @article{label,
        title = {Best paper ever},
        author = {Best author in universe},
        location = {Earth},
        publisher = {fiend},
        date = {0000},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{the}

\begin{document}
    Why the heck is there a space:\cite{label}?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, thanks, this is it. I did not think about how spacing affect commands.