# What does "{%" mean?

Tags: braces, scoping, percent-sign

What does "{%" (a brace followed by a percent) mean, and what is it called if I want to find the documentation for it?

Here is an example.

```
\newcommand{\atest}
{%

\includegraphics[width=1in]{./icpw logo spaced.PNG}\\Joe Dirt\\1 Lambda Street\\Anyplace, NY 12345
}
```

Comment: This is just to suppress spurious spaces.

Comment: bracket is not a part of the *%*, that bracket lines up with the one in the end, that bracket seems (to me) that is a part of [`\newcommand` syntax](https://www.math.uh.edu/~torok/math_6298/latex/macros.html)..

Comment: Does these answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/why-the-end-of-line-in-macro-definitions ( <- probably a duplicate) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat

Comment: Note that the empty line inside your `\atest` definition is probably unwanted and might do harm (that is an implicit `\par` token you're putting there, so every time you'd use that macro it would be `\par\inludegraphics...` instead of just `\includegraphics...`)