# Unexpected spaces in the text with putmarginpar multicol

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, setspace

How to suppress the unexpected space between the characters ==> and <==, due to the putmarginpar, please? (I work with a strengthen text, because I have few space in my document)

```
\documentclass[a5paper, para]{book}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.3cm, includeheadfoot] {geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{ifthen, pgffor}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\columnsep}{3mm}\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1mm}
\setstretch{0.80}\fontdimen2\font=0.25em\fontdimen3\font=0.25em

\makeatletter
\def\putmarginpar#1#2{
  \zsavepos{#1}
  \ifnum6139194>\number\zposx{#1}%
    \hbox to 0pt{\hskip\dimexpr-\zposx{#1}sp +1.0cm \relax#2}
  \else
    \hbox to 0pt{\hskip\dimexpr-\zposx{#1}sp +20.5cm \relax#2}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bv}{This is a sample of a text.}
\newcommand{\bvn}[2]{\foreach \n in {#1,...,#2} { \bv}}
\newcommand{\txt}[2]{\foreach \n in {#1,...,#2} {
    \bvn{1}{5}\textcolor{red}{==>}\putmarginpar{40:1:1}{1}\textcolor{red}{<==}\bvn{1}{5}\\
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\txt{1}{9}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This is just a shot in the dark (not tested).  In the definition of `\putmarginpar` there are an awful lot of "spurious spaces".  Remember that an end-of-line is treated as a space.  So if you "protect" those positions -- following an opening or closing brace, for example -- with a `%`, it won't be possible for a space to be output there.

Comment: Ah OK. With this, it is better, but there is still unexpected spaces. Thanks for your rapid response

Comment: \def\putmarginnote#1{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage{\begingroup\docolaction{\reversemarginpar}{}{}\oldmarginnote{#1}\endgroup}\else{\begingroup\docolaction{}{}{\reversemarginpar}\oldmarginnote{#1}\endgroup}\fi}

Comment: You might include that code as an addendum to the question, to give a better starting point for someone able to experiment.

Comment: I thank you  for your help. Finally, the "unexpected" spaces are very "descreet". I have now a beautiful text!

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [Why the end-of-line `%` in macro definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40946)  (It, in turn, is noted as a duplicate to a question that has answers with more basic explanations.)

Comment: Thanks for your useful recall. I am new with Latex, have read the documentation, but forgot this point !