# Large negative spaces

Tags: spacing

I know about `\!` which creates a thin negative space but is there any native command for large negative spaces (like `quad` or `qquad` for positive spaces) ?

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them/41484#41484 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing

Comment: A simpler method is: `bla \rlap{math}path bla`. This renders the two words left aligned. For right alignment use `\llap`.

Comment: why not define something like \def\nquad{\!\!\!\!\!}, ...?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

In text mode: `\kern-1em` equals "minus quad"

In math mode: `\mkern-18mu` equals "minus quad"

For "minus qquad" use `-2em` or `-36mu` respectively.

Comment: what about negative simple space in text mode? (according to the selected font)

Answer (score 64):

For LaTeX, horizontal spacing is achieved using `\hspace{<len>}` where `<len>` is a length (either positive or negative); TeX's equivalent to `\hskip`. Since `\quad` [`\qquad`] is equivalent to a horizontal skip of `1em` [`2em`], use `\hspace{-1em}` [`\hspace{-2em}`] to obtain a negative space amount.

`\kern` inserts a space depending on the mode that TeX is in, and could therefore be either vertical *or* horizontal.

Text-based spacing can be inserted using any of the `\phantom`-related commands: `\phantom{<stuff>}`, or `\hphantom{<stuff>}`, for example.

Comment: I would also love to use some `phantom`-like command but for negative space, i.e., going back in an amount given by a _forward-written_ word. Example, I want to write _math_ over _path_. Then my code should be: `math \negphantom{math} path`. Is it possible in an easy way? Maybe folding a `phantom` inside something to rotate/reflect it? But would that provide the same placement for the _h_'s of _math_ and _path_?

Comment: Or maybe some way of getting the size in pt of `{whichever strange code object}` may print in the pdf? (like `\fontcharwd`..., but not for simple characters, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152550/36389))

Comment: My approach for my first comment is: `math\begin{rotate}{180}\scalebox{-1}[-1]{p\phantom{ath}}\end{rotate}`, which requires the `rotating` package and also `graphicx`. 

It would be nice to do with `rotatebox` what I do with the `rotate` environment, in order to avoid using both packages, but I haven't be able due to the way it rotates or keeps a fixed center.

Comment: @Andrestand: Use `\newcommand{\negphantom}[1]{\settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}\hspace*{-\dimen0}}`.

Comment: that way provides a bad alignment when using `math \negphantom{math} path`, but the commands `\settowidth`, `\width`, etc. were what I was looking for. Reading about them I found I can define `\negphantom` also like: `bla math\makebox[-\width]{path}\makebox[\width]{\phantom{path}} bla`. To ask `LaTeX` to give or print the value of variables I may read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125016/how-to-display-command-name-and-its-value)...

Comment: I do not understand what you need to create the second makebox-command for @Andrestand. `bla math\makebox[-\width]{path}\phantom{path} bla` renders the exact same for me. Anyway, thanks a lot for the code!

Comment: What about: `\mbox{\rlap{math}}path`

Answer (score 4):

What about simply `\!\!` or `\!\!\!` ?
It worked for me fine...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please note that outside of code environments the backslash `\` is treated as an escape character by MarkDown, this is why none of the backslashes you typed originally showed up. I've wrapped them in code blocks so now they show.