# Typesetting of volume integral

Tags: math-mode, equations, typography

This question has been bugging me for a long time: How do I properly typeset volume integrals? I would like to use the convention often used in Physics: `d^3x=dV` and `\int dx f(x)` instead of `\int f(x) dx`

Example:

```
    The kinetic energy is simply given by
    \begin{equation}
      T = \int\,\mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{x}\frac{\rho}{2} \mathbf{\dot x}^2 = \frac{3}{10}M\dot R^2\;.
    \end{equation}
```

But the integral looks somehow bad as the spacing between the x and the d is too big. How can I change this?

Comment: you can tweak the spacing by yourself, try with `\!` or `\mkern`. This may be useful or not: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67912/large-negative-spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the following is what you're after:

[image: output]

I *raised* the `3` quite a bit and slightly moved it to the left; this way I could move the `x` much closer to the `d`. Here's the code for a command `\d` that takes one optional and one mandatory argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand*\d[2][]{%
  \mathrm{d}%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
    \rule{-0.05em}{1.9ex}^{#1}\!
  \fi
  #2\,
  }
\begin{document}
\[
  \int \d[3]{\mathbf{x}} \frac{\rho}{2} \mathbf{\dot x}^2 \qquad
  \int \d{\mathbf{y}} f(\mathbf{y})
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that this only works for "small" integration variables like `x`. Moreover, I removed the `\,` between `\int` and `\mathrm{d}` that you had and put it *after* the differential instead. You can of course adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! A friend pointed out, though, that the "x" should not be bold, as it is not a vector in that context. What do you say to that?

Comment: If the `x` in `\dot x` is bold, than I'd also make it bold in the differential. (Personally, as a mathematician, I make neither of them bold.)