# How can I replace a full stop with an image?

Tags: graphics, punctuation

I would like to hide an easter egg in my document by replacing the last full stop of my conclusion with a (vector) image scaled down to pass as a punctuation, almost like a microdot.  Is this possible to do without too much work?

The image itself is an SVG which I have converted to a TikZ image using InkScape, but if another format is better suited for this I can convert it again.  The document is going to be published as a PDF so I'm hoping that someone with a keen eye may notice and zoom in enough to see the image.

Comment: You can put `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` anywhere.

Comment: @egreg Sure, but I want it to look like a full stop to the casual observer so it needs to be placed and scaled correctly.

Comment: I usually hide some text in "white" pages with `\textcolor{white}{hidden message}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main problem is making the fake dot sufficiently dark. I used a PDF file of a text inside a circle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
This is the end.

This is the end%
  \makebox[\fontcharwd\font`.][c]{%
    \resizebox{\fontcharht\font`.}{!}{%
       \includegraphics{fakedot}% here put whatever you like
    }%
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This did exactly what I wanted it to.  In the end I decided to use a black silhouette to get it to look as dark as possible.