# Negative space equal the length of a string?

Tags: spacing, symbols

I'm trying to create symbols, like the Interrobang (basically the ? and ! combined into one punctuation mark), that are the result of two overlapping symbols. Something like this can be produced with two negative spaces, but it isn't anywhere near perfect.

I've seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67912/large-negative-spaces) and have tried using `\mkern{}` and `\kern{}`, but they aren't working for the *width* of the text.

Basically, I need a command that will operate like: `? \negspace{?} !`. This will essentially type a ?, go back the width of a ?, and type a !. (sort of like the ← key on a typewriter.) Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're asking for is an overlapping macro. Either use `\rlap` (which produces a `r`ight over`lap`):

```
\rlap{?}!
```

or `\llap` (which produces a `l`eft over`lap`):

```
?\llap{!}
```

The order of the punctuation `?` and `!` doesn't really matter, although they have different widths (and therefore may set slightly differently when switched around). 
The LaTeX2e equivalent is `\makebox[0pt][l]{?}!` (`?\makebox[0pt][r]{!}`) which sets `?` in a zero-width box that is `l`eft-aligned, followed by a now-overwriting `!`. [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) provides similar functionality in a host of user-friendly interface macros.

Instead of fiddling with the spacing using a "back-spacing" technique, overlay symbols using `\ooalign`. However, [`textcomp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) already provides `\textinterrobang`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand{\interrobang}{{\ooalign{?\cr\hss!\kern .025em\hss}}}
\begin{document}

I came! I saw? I conquered\textinterrobang{} And now I'm leaving.

I came! I saw? I conquered\interrobang{} And now I'm leaving.

\end{document}
```

<sub>See [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22371/5764) for [a quick course in `\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).</sub>

Comment: Could you explain to me the little commands (`\cr`,`\hss`,etc.)?

Comment: Hmm, I'd much prefer having additional braces around `\ooalign`. Try putting `\the\lineskiplimit` just after `\begin{document}` and immediately before `\end{document}`. Then you'll know why!

Comment: Did you enjoy seeing the value of `\lineskiplimit`? ;-)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien: `\cr` literally means `c`arraige `r`eturn, like inserting a line break or using ``\\`` in a `tabular` or `array`. `\hss` means `h`orizontal `s`tretch or `s`hrink, which inserts "glue" that is "infinitely shrinkable as
well as infinitely stretchable" (taken from the [TeXbook](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbook)). Using `\hss<stuff>\hss` is typically used to center content).

Comment: @egreg: Yes and no. :)