# What are skip values?

Tags: titlesec, lengths

On page 5 of the `titlesec` manual (released on June 14, 2000), it is written that full skip values, including the `plus` and `minus` parameters can be abbreviated as * *n*.

The example on page 24-25 (the code I am referring to is actually on page 25) input the following as a full skip value:

`1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex`

Could you please explain what that means and where it is applicable?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them/41488#41488