# Change line spacing of \\

Tags: line-spacing

I have a block of text:

```
Blah: \\
line1 \\
line2 \\
line3 \\
Blah.
```

I want to change the line spacing between lines 1-3 only.  But somehow I cannot do that with `\linespread{}` or `\setstretch{}` -- the line spacing created by `\\` seems to be unaffected by those commands.  What can I do?

Comment: In which context are you using those manual line breaks? You could use the optional argument, as in `\\[-5pt]` or `\\[15pt]`, but if you tell us the real-case use at hand, perhaps we could suggest better alternatives?

Comment: With `\\[<amount of vertical space>]`. For example `\\[3pt]` ?

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem beautifully.

Comment: I was trying to inline some code in a literary work.  Don't want to invoke the algorithms package :)

Comment: Is there a way to change the default value ?

Answer (score 4):

I would have a look on the package `listings` if you want to add code to your text.

For your example, you may use any addition of vertical space as mentioned here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41488

Here are some examples:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent   
Blah: \\[1cm]
line1 \medskip\\ % or smallskip or bigskip
line2 \vspace{1cm}\\
line3 \\
Blah.
\end{document}
```