# Is using \\[.5 \baselineskip] bad practice?

Tags: typography, line-spacing, best-practices

I've developed the habit of using `\\[.5\baselineskip]` to indicate
that a part of a bigger argument ended in that line. I found this
quite helpful to structure bigger arguments.

By now, I start questioning myself if that might be bad practice. In particular concerning the readability of documents.

If there is someone here with experience in professional typesetting with
well reasoned arguments for, or against this practice, I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably bad practice, although hard to say with no context.

Firstly `\\` does not end the paragraph. If your narrative reaches a point where a large visual break is needed then a paragraph break would seem more natural.

If all paragraph breaks need the same visual skip then there is nothing more to do, but if this is a special break then using

```
blah blah blah.

\newthought

Blah blah blah
```

Not only makes the source document more readable, and you can define `\newthought` in one place to affect all such constructs in the document, starting with

```
\newcommand\newthought{\par\vspace{.5\baselineskip}}
```

Comment: Might want to steal some code from memoirs fancybreak macro, then the paragraph after the break will not be indented.

Comment: There's already `\bigskip` which bascially nudges things down by `\bigskipamount` (if I remember correctly)...

Comment: @Seamus Indeed. I was actually thinking of posting about that.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be a bit more robust to add `\par` to the definition?

Comment: @Tobi not when used like this, with blanks lines around it, then the par is already implied. But of course not all users tend to write their code readable like this

Comment: @daleif but if it is a new paragraph then it isn't clear why you'd want to suppress indentation.

Comment: @Seamus sure but it's better to have a specific command even if you initially just define it to be `\bigskip`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks a lot for the quick answer . I will change my style in that direction. Also thanks to all others for the interesting discussions. Always reminds me, that there still is a lot to learn about typesetting.

Comment: @Tobi done. (`\par`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if it is a new paragraph, then why the space? There is no need for it. If it is not indented, then the blank space above it should in dictate we are starting something new

Comment: @daleif well perhaps (your reasoning is that it's like an invisible section heading) the OP doesn't give much context so you could be right:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that  is usually what people around here use it for. Though I'm trying to teach them to keep the use at a minimum. Sadly I'm currently seeing an increase in the use of ``\\`` in the text, basically lots of new users does not understand the paragraph and gets really bad advise from their project advisors (who foes not have a clue either)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, your definition of `.5\baselineskip` is exactly the length of `\medskip`, which is equivalent to `\vspace{\medskipamount}`. If we show these values we get:

```
\verb!\baselineskip =! \the\baselineskip

\verb!     \medskip =! \the\medskipamount
```

[image]

So if we define a new length of that size, it'll look like `\medskip`. Of course, the major difference would be the stretchable lengths: the `plus` indicates how much it will be stretched, and the `minus` how much it will be shrinked, if required. See [this egreg's answer for more info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41488/4778).

So here's a comparison between `\newarg`, a new command that is half a line, and `\medskip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\sms
\setlength\sms{.5\baselineskip} 

\newcommand\newarg{\par\vspace{\sms}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\newarg

\lipsum[66]

\medskip

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```