# How to adding vertical spacing in \raggedright or \RaggedRight

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, paragraphs

I usually use `\\`, `\par`, `\newline`, etc. to add whitespace to LaTeX. However, when I use raggedRight, the pdflatex spits out a ton of messages saying "There's no line here to end." Ultimately, all vertical whitespace is removed.

My question is, is it possible to add whitespace to a raggedRight environment? If so, how? If not, what can I use to successfully justify my text to the left and maintain the whitespace as it is?

Comment: you should almost never need any of those commands. `\\ ` gives the no line here to end error if it is at the start of a paragraph, whether or not raggedright is in force. You perhaps should give a complete example that generates the error so people can suggest alternative code.

Comment: For special cases when you need to add anomalous space after a linebreak you can  use `\\[2cm]`

Comment: to expand on what david has said, `\par` or a blank line will *not* trigger the "no line here to end" message.  so they can safely be used to cause a new line to start.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\\\\`, I found that using `\smallskip`,`\medskip`, `\bigskip`, and other commands from [Lengths and when to use them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them) works well. Along with David Carlisle's suggestion of using the optional length parameter after `\\` to specify a length of vertical white-space.