# Short interline spacing after \item in customized description environment

Tags: line-spacing, enumitem, description

I'm working on a technical guide, and I have a list of descriptions of different commands that can be run. Some of these commands have aliases or alternative invocations, and I want them to have the same description body. Using the `enumitem` package, I've managed to customize this to look the way I want. What I have looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\SetLabelAlign{parleft}{\parbox[t]\textwidth{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline,labelindent=0em,align=parleft]
\item[There's just one phrase, notice hanging characters]
    Here Is The Definition Of The Phrase. \lipsum[11]
\item[This is the first phrase \newline Notice hanging characters in the second phrase]
    Here Is The Definition Of The Phrase. \lipsum[47]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Items that just have a single line look perfectly fine to me, but when there are multiple lines, the spacing between the last line in the `\item` and the following description is much shorter than the spacing between the lines inside the item and between single-line items and their descriptions:

[image: Shorter interline spacing for multi-line text]

I have two questions:

- To help my understanding of TeX, why is the space after the `\parbox` that contains a single line correct, but the space after the one with two lines is not?
- How can I fix this so that the space after the last line in every `\item` to the description is equivalent?

Note that this document is auto-generated, so a solution that doesn't require manual intervention for each multi-line item is preferred, but I can customize the generation as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Zarko `\parbox[<vertical placement>]{<width>}{<contents>}`, but isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you use parboc alone. My idea was to correct determine parobx width, a content is given by `\item`, as far as I understand `enumitem`'s options. I'm not sure anymore, I need to check documentation (but not tonight, I need some sleep :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a way of achieving what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{parleft}{\parbox[t]\textwidth{#1\smallskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[style=nextline,labelindent=0em,align=parleft]
  \item[There's just one phrase, notice hanging characters]
  Here Is The Definition Of The Phrase. \lipsum[11]
  \item[This is the first phrase  \newline Notice hanging characters in the second phrase]
  Here Is The Definition Of The Phrase. \lipsum[47]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: wide multiline boxed labels]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix it! After reading about shrinking/stretching in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41488/105633 I think I understand why this change works and doesn't make the single-line items look like they have too much space, but I'm still confused about why the \parbox didn't have any space after it originally.

Comment: There's something odd going on with the way `enumitem` is handling `\parbox` which I don't understand. I wouldn't have expected Zarko's suggestions to work at all without error. Yet they do in this specific context. (They don't do what you wanted, but they don't give errors.) So I'm a bit confused about what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `\vskip\partopsep` seem to work:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\SetLabelAlign{parleft}{\parbox[t]\textwidth{#1\vskip\partopsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=unboxed,labelindent=0em,align=parleft]
\item[There's just one phrase, notice hanging characters]
    Here Is The Definition Of The Phrase. \lipsum[11]
\item[This is the first phrase \newline Notice hanging characters in the second phrase]
    Here Is The Definition Of The Phrase. \lipsum[47]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]