# Signature description at the bottom of a document

Tags: spacing

I want to put a description which signature goes where and who signed there at the bottom of a document. For the moment I use `\vspace` with a hand-chosen value that brings down this stuff to the bottom. But of course this is not an elegant solution, and I am sure one can do much better ;)

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\vspace{80mm}

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Person 1
\vspace{30mm}

Person 2\\
\columnbreak

Person 3
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\vfill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Top content...

\vfill

Bottom content.
\end{document}
```

See [this TEX-SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them/41488#41488) for futher information.

Comment: Possibly `\nopagebreak\vfill`.