# New-lines in tex source. What are the rules?

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I recently discovered that if I put a `%` symbol above and below my equations when I used `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` that my output PDF is made more compact, as tex interprets a new line as a new paragraph.

Previously I had been using `\noindent` to prevent indentation after equations and other structures such as `\begin{itemize}`.

Here is an example:

```
\subsection{Why Quantum Field Theory?}

Quantum Field Theory inevitably emerges from ``quantum mechanics'' + ``relativity''. It is the language of the Standard Model of Particle Physics. (QFT + Gauge Symmetry.)

\begin{itemize}
    \item {QFT + Gauge $\to$ All of Nature - Gravity}
\end{itemize}

\noindent
Particle collision cross section calculations are done in the framework of QFT.
```

And here is another example from a different section.

```
\subsection{Hamiltonian Formalism}

Equivalent to the Lagrangian formalism is the Hamiltonian formalism. The conjugate momentum is defined $p_i=\pderiv{L}{\dot{q}_i}$.\footnote{Note that this does \textit{not} correspond to the momentum in all systems.} The Hamiltonian is obtained from a Legendre Transform [proof]

\begin{equation}
    H(q_i,p_i)=\sum_i p_i \dot{q}_i-L(q_i,\dot{q}_i)
\end{equation}

\noindent
For a single particle $L=\tfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2-V(x)$. $\pderiv{L}{\dot{x}}=m\dot{x}$, $H(x,p)=\tfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2+V(x)$, which in this case corresponds to the total energy.

Newtons Law can be derived,

\[\deriv{}{t}\left(\pderiv{L}{\dot{x}}\right)=m\ddot{x}=\deriv{V(x)}{x}=F(x)\]

\noindent
Hamiltons Equations are used to derive equations of motion

\begin{align}
    \pderiv{H}{q_i}&=-\dot{p}_i\\\pderiv{H}{p_i}&=\dot{q}_i
\end{align}
```

You can see I've used `\noindent` a lot to get the indentation right.

I now think that I might be writing my tex code in a way which is non-optimal.

Is it better practice to put `%`'s on all blank lines where I do not want a new paragraph to start?

Comment: A blank line is interpreted as a paragraph break.  A `%` "erases" the remainder of the input line (including the terminating linefeed, which is typically interpreted as a space).  Both of those circumstances potentially bring into play vertical spacing mechanisms that are built into LaTeX.  For example, `\parskip` is a vertical length associated with paragraph breaks.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines for discussion of `%` and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them/41488#41488 for vertical spacing lengths associated with LaTeX.

Comment: The better practice comes from not using `\noindent` to 'fake' not starting a new paragraph. If it is not a new paragraph, don't leave a blank line. What makes better sense for *input* markup is a different question. Because I do like to have environments separated from the main text, but because it is 'wrong' to use `\noindent` to 'fix' the blank space, the alternative is to use `%` to otherwise 'hide' the blank lines: this gives visually separates environments in the input file without creating new (semantic) paragraphs in the output that are 'cancelled' or 'hidden' by means of a `\noindent`

Answer (score 5):

Examine the examples here, to see that a blank line indicates a paragraph break, but placing a `%` eliminates the interpretation of the rest of the line, including the linebreak.

Note that if a linebreak is followed by a non-blank line, the linebreak is interpreted as a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
a
b

c

\noindent is interpreted as ``a <sp> b <sp> <par> c''

a%
b

c

\noindent is interpreted as ``a b <sp> <par> c''

a
b
%
c

\noindent is interpreted as ``a <sp> b <sp> c''

a%
b
%
c

\noindent is interpreted as ``a b <sp> c''

a%
b%
%
c

\noindent is interpreted as ``a b c''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Never ever leave a blank line before a math display. Never use `\noindent` in a document (well, hardly ever): using it more than once or twice means there's something wrong in your way of typing.

You *can* comment an otherwise blank line, but with decent syntax coloring you don't really need such tricks.

```
\subsection{Hamiltonian Formalism}

Equivalent to the Lagrangian formalism is the Hamiltonian formalism. The conjugate 
momentum is defined $p_i=\pderiv{L}{\dot{q}_i}$.\footnote{Note that this does 
  \textit{not} correspond to the momentum in all systems.} The Hamiltonian is 
obtained from a Legendre Transform [proof]
\begin{equation}
  H(q_i,p_i)=\sum_i p_i \dot{q}_i-L(q_i,\dot{q}_i)
\end{equation}
For a single particle $L=\tfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2-V(x)$. 
$\pderiv{L}{\dot{x}}=m\dot{x}$, $H(x,p)=\tfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2+V(x)$, which in 
this case corresponds to the total energy.

Newtons Law can be derived,
\begin{equation*}
  \deriv{}{t}\left(\pderiv{L}{\dot{x}}\right)=m\ddot{x}=\deriv{V(x)}{x}=F(x)  
\end{equation*}
Hamiltons Equations are used to derive equations of motion
\begin{align}
  \pderiv{H}{q_i} &= -\dot{p}_i \\
  \pderiv{H}{p_i} &= \dot{q}_i
\end{align}
```

[image]

Note `equation*` instead of `equation`: it's easier to remove or add a `*` instead of changing `\[` and `\]` into `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to end the paragraph it is clearest  not  to add   the end of paragraph instruction  (blank line) . Adding it then commenting it out works but is more convoluted than necessary.  Ending the paragraph then starting a new one with noindent  is completely different and should be rarely needed