# Remove newline function/interaction

Tags: spacing

Is it possible to make it so that LaTeX will ignore newlines in the source? e.g. it shouldn't do anything to the output if I use an empty line.

I like to keep my source fairly spaced out for easier reading, but that becomes fairly difficult since an empty line forces a new paragraph.

Comment: placing `%` at the beginning of any blank line that shouldn't mark a paragraph break is the usual method.  see [New-lines in tex source. What are the rules?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345230/579) for a discussion, and in particular the comment with links.

Comment: You could use `\catcode13=10` and then you have to use `\par` to indicate paragraphs. But this could possibly mess up other things, so I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use comment sign between lines latex will interpret it as a single paragraph.

example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

dakhfsdlkfjdhsflgkjhfglksjdhfglkjdfshgldfkjghdflkgjhdflghk
%
dfkhdlskfjghldsfkjghdlsfkjghdklsfghldfksjg

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Any way to make this default?