# In beamerposter, how to have a left-aligned figure + caption on right side within a block, without having to use \frame?

Tags: captions, beamerposter

Here is the best example I have so far, but it is still unsatisfactory because the caption is not RIGHT NEXT to the image, and the image is in an odd spot, when I want it to be on the left side.

Some preamble on why I need it to be exactly like this:

1. I'm making a poster with beamer, with a bunch of other elements. Using the \frame style will mess up with everything else I've done for the same page. I felt like redacting the other parts will take too much work, so I only posted the part I'm having trouble with.
2. I can't use the \SCfigure command with beamer, so that alternative doesn't work for me. It just hangs while compiling.
3. The \floatrow packages clash with the block contents, so that won't work either.

Here is a crudely edited image in paint, of what I want: [image].

My code:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} 
%\mode<presentation> {  %% check http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php for examples           

  \usetheme{Berlin}    %% you should define your own theme e.g. for big headlines using your own logos 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\boldmath
\usepackage[size=custom,width=95,height=232.5,scale=1.98]{beamerposter} % e.g. for custom size poster
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{block}{\large \space Contacts}
\newline    


\begin{figure}
    \begin{columns}%
        \begin{column}{0\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[height=8cm, width=7cm]{example-image}
        \end{column}%
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}%
            \caption*{Dr Person Person No 2 \newline Tel: 12345612331023  \newline Email: guyman1@person.com}
        \end{column}%
    \end{columns}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{columns}%
        \begin{column}{0\textwidth}%
            \includegraphics[height=8cm, width=7cm]{example-image}
        \end{column}%
        \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}%
            \caption*{Dr Person Person No 1 \newline Tel: 12345612331023  \newline Email: guyman2@person.com}
        \end{column}%
    \end{columns}
\end{figure}

\end{block}

\end{document}
```

And the section generated after compiling:
[image]

Sorry that this isn't an exactly minimal or even a good example, I'm particularly new with LaTeX, and I'm not sure which package to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to remove the `figure` stuff that is responsible for centering the information and to typeset the contents just as two paragraphs.

```
\begin{block}{\large \space Contacts}
\bigskip
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=8cm, width=7cm]{example-image}}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{l}
Dr Person Person No 2\\
Tel: 12345612331023\\
Email: guyman1@person.com
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=8cm, width=7cm]{example-image}}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{l}
Dr Person Person No 1\\
Tel: 12345612331023\\
Email: guyman1@person.com
\end{tabular}
\end{block}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} 
%\mode<presentation> {  %% check http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php for examples           

\usetheme{Berlin}    %% you should define your own theme e.g. for big headlines using your own logos 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\boldmath
\usepackage[size=custom,width=95,height=232.5,scale=1.98]{beamerposter} % e.g. for custom size poster
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{block}{\large \space Contacts}
\bigskip
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=8cm, width=7cm]{example-image}}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{l}
Dr Person Person No 2\\
Tel: 12345612331023\\
Email: guyman1@person.com
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=8cm, width=7cm]{example-image}}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{l}
Dr Person Person No 1\\
Tel: 12345612331023\\
Email: guyman1@person.com
\end{tabular}
\end{block}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What an elegant solution! Learned a couple of new commands today (especially that \\ lineskip, super convenient). Really appreciate the help! If you don't mind me asking, can you explain a bit about the general field you entered? Particularly what a \tabular is, along with \bigskip, \raisebox, and \quad?

Comment: @NisbahMumtaz These are standard LaTeX commands, documented in any LaTeX intro. See [raisebox](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#raisebox), [tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment), [spacing commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41488/110998).