# music and enumerate together

Tags: enumerate, musixtex

I am using `musixtex` for writing music. I want to use environment `music` with `enumerate`. See this code -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   \begin{music}
            \setclef{1}{\alto}
            \startextract
            \notes \wh{c} \en
            \endextract
        \end{music}
        \hrule
        \item   \begin{music}
            \setclef{1}{\alto}
            \startextract
            \notes \wh{g} \en
            \endextract
        \end{music}
        \hrule
        \item   \begin{music}
            \setclef{1}{\alto}
            \startextract
            \notes \wh{g} \en
            \endextract
        \end{music}
        \hrule
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This renders the following output. It is evident that the enumeration has happened wrongly. What can be the cause of this and how to solve this?

[image]

---

### Solution provided by @Piroooh and some further doubts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule
\item\mbox{\null}

\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\hrule

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

See 9th and 17th point. The enumeration and the point are on different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause :**
It's due to the height of the `music` environment which starts from the bottom of the line in LaTeX. It's the same problem for each environment next to the `\item` command. (Minipage, includegraphics,...)

---

**Solution :**
You can avoid this behaviour by adding `\mbox{\null}` and a blank line after the `\item` command. It's the easiest way to achieve what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item   \mbox{\null}

        \begin{music}
            \setclef{1}{\alto}
            \startextract
            \notes \wh{c} \en
            \endextract
        \end{music}
        \hrule
        \item   \mbox{\null}

        \begin{music}
            \setclef{1}{\alto}
            \startextract
            \notes \wh{g} \en
            \endextract
        \end{music}
        \hrule
        \item   \mbox{\null}

        \begin{music}
            \setclef{1}{\alto}
            \startextract
            \notes \wh{g} \en
            \endextract
        \end{music}
        \hrule
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output]

Comment: Ok, really a good solution. Also thanks for the explanation, but this is still creating a problem for large lists. See the edit.

Comment: By this logic I can also have `\item\phantom{text}\\` and then my music environment. I tried it and it works fine, I want a real solution which will enumerate the music correctly.

Comment: Why not simply `\mbox{}`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I found the best. Thanks @Pirooh and @egreg.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{c} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}

\item \mbox{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{music}
\setclef{1}{\alto}
\startextract
\notes \wh{g} \en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `\mbox{}`, because of `minipage`; also `\textwidth` should be `\linewidth`.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. Can you explain the difference between `textwidth` and `linewidth`?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them/41488#41488