# negative character space (negative version of `\ `)

Tags: spacing, lengths

There is a negative thinspace `\!` which is a negative version of `\,`.

Is there a negative version of normal character space `\` too?

I could not find it in: [Lengths and when to use them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41476/128042), [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing), https://mylatexnotes.wordpress.com/2017/05/09/text-negative-white-spaces/

Comment: Note that `\ ` could shrink/expand with the text, so it's not fixed.

Comment: The value of the space is stored in the font parameter`\fontdimen2` but as Werner said that can shrink or stretch (`\fontdimen3` and `\fontdimen4`) so the space isn't really fixed. Are you by any chance looking for something like `\unskip`?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

a\ b

a\ \hspace{-\fontdimen2\font plus -\fontdimen3\font minus -\fontdimen4\font}b

\end{document}
```

The interword spacing is set by the font so you can use `\hspace{-\fontdimen2\font plus -\fontdimen3\font minus -\fontdimen4\font}` as shown, but it is hard to think of any cases where this is useful. As commented it may be that you are looking for `\unskip`
`a \unskip b` typesets as `ab` by removing the glue node rather than adding a second negative glue node.