# How to make vspace being canceled at begin of minipage

Tags: spacing, minipage

`\vspace` at the beginning of a real page is canceled but at the beginning of a minipage it is faithfully added.

How could I modify `\vspace` (or the minipage-environment) to behave in the same way as at a real page break, i.e. I want the vspace ignored first in the minipage but honored anywhere else.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\vspace{1cm}
test

\clearpage
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vspace{1cm} %should be ignored
test
\vspace{1cm} %should be kept
test
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also try [the following code](https://pastebin.com/raw/F5y9KvAe), based on [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580744/5764).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myvspace[1]{\if@minipage\else\vspace{#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\vspace{1cm}
test

\clearpage
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\myvspace{1cm} %should be ignored
test
\myvspace{1cm} %should be kept
test
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I left it as you had it but did you intend a paragraph break so there was vertical space between the `test` ? You can not see the second vspace as it comes after the text.

The `\if@minpage` is true at the start of a minipage and set false at the first paragraph, it is used.

As a perhaps better alternative to defining your own command you could use the standard LaTeX `\addvspace` command which already includes this test (you would then have to have a paragraph break though as `\addvspace` in horizontal mode is an error.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\clearpage
\addvspace{1cm}
test

\clearpage
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\addvspace{1cm} %should be ignored
test

\addvspace{1cm} %should be kept
test
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Oh yes, I certainly wanted the space between the two "test" in the minipage; that was a stupid copy-paste mistake that I left out the empty line. `\addvspace` will do very well for me -- I just didn't know that it would do the check. Is there perhaps a comprehensive source somewhere about all the spacing commands with their specific properties/differences?

Comment: Would the `\if@minipage` work for all environments?

Comment: @Florian for a list perhaps this even though egreg wrote it:-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them/41488#41488  I am not sure what you mean, `\if@minipage` is just set by `minipage`.

Comment: Thanks again! The list is very helpful though obviously not covering everything: To know that `\addvspace` will be canceled out by minipages I'll still have to ask you ;) As for the other question I was wondering whether I can expect an equivavalent variable set by every environment (something like `\if@quote`) which I could use to do things.

Comment: @Florian no it is specifically set by minipage but checked by environments like quote and lists so that they behave at the top of a minipage like they behave at the top of a page

Comment: @Florian in the very latest latex release every enviornment does have a hook at the start and end at which you can add code, but that is rather different.