# Situational assessment about vertical space commands

Tags: spacing

I would like some assessment on the situational utilities of various vertical space commands, namely: `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, `\bigskip`, `\vspace*{value}`, `\\[value]`.

`\smallskip`, `\medskip`, `\bigskip`, and `\vfill` are formed using `\vspace`.

But the above do not produce a vertical space in the following code

```latex
    \documentclass{book}
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm,
      top=21mm, bottom=21mm}
    
    \usepackage{fix-cm}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\normalsize{%
       \@setfontsize\normalsize{13pt}{15pt}
       \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
       \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
       \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
       \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
       \let\@listi\@listI}
    \makeatother
    
    \usepackage{bm}                % makes bold arguments
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}  % loads 317 named rgb colours
    
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    
    \boldmath
    \renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}
    
    \newcommand\blskip{\\[0.3\baselineskip]}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \normalsize
    
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
    \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

    \section{Fourier Transform}

    \begin{theorem}
      [\color{blue} \textbf{Convolution Property of Fourier Transform}]
      \label{convolution}
    
      \textcolor{blue}{\bigskip This is not insterted on a new line}
      \textcolor{blue}{\vspace{8pt} This does not work either}
    
      \textcolor{blue}{\blskip This worked as intended}
    
      The Fourier transform of the product of two functions, \( u_1(t) \)
      and \( u_2(t) \), is equal to the product of the Fourier transforms
      \( F(u_1) \) and \( F(u_2) \).
    
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}

What is happening?  How does the utilisation of `\\{skip}`, but the others based upon `\vspace` do not?
```

Comment: The answers to this [question contain decent details](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41476/245306) that may help.

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate based on the first question but your edits point to different issues so I retract it. In the future, when you post a code sample, could you make sure the code can compile as it is please? As in, include from `\documentclass{book}` etc, include relevant packages (such as `\usepackage{amsmath}`, key definitions such as defining `\newtheorem` etc. It just makes it easier to help for the future, this contains more information on MWE's [(minimal working examples)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/245306). Hope someone can help answer this!

Comment: It is bad style to have _any_ explicit vertical spaces in the document but despite the name ` `\newcommand\blskip{\\[0.3\baselineskip]}` does not add a vertical skip it adds a line break and will generate errors where you have used it.  Please always provide a real test document not just a fragment that does not run on its own.

Comment: One should not be too prescriptive on good style, if a user is sure additional vertical spacing is required, particularly for long proofs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right to state that it is a line break actually.  So will change the name accordingly.  Although it does add some vertical space of `0.3\baselineskip`.

Comment: see my answer, it dosn't add it in a form that you want to use here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design the initial text of the theorem is inline, the`amsthm` documatioon shows a `break` style that always starts a new line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,color}
\newtheoremstyle{break}%
{}{}%           % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
{\itshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{}%
{\newline}{}

\theoremstyle{break}

\newtheorem{theorem}{thm}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand\blskip{\\[0.3\baselineskip]}
    
    \begin{theorem}
      [\color{blue} \textbf{Convolution Property of Fourier Transform}]
      \label{convolution}
    
      \textcolor{blue}{\bigskip This is not insterted on a new line}
      \textcolor{blue}{\vspace{8pt} This does not work either}
    
      \textcolor{blue}{\blskip This worked as intended}
    
      The Fourier transform of the product of two functions, \( u_1(t) \)
      and \( u_2(t) \), is equal to the product of the Fourier transforms
      \( F(u_1) \) and \( F(u_2) \).
    
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

`\textcolor` (ulike `\color`) starts a paragraph and horizontal mode, so your `\bigskip` (which is `\vspace{\bigskipamount}`)  does work but adds vertical sppace *after* the paragraph has been broken in to lines and adds it immediately *after* the line that has the vadjust node containing the skip, so the vertical space appears after the first line of the paragraph, not before the paragraph.

Conversely  the last line, igoring the color is

`\mbox{}\\[0.3\baselineskip]`

so you get parskip space then a "white" line of a paragraph, with just the paragraph indentation box, then you get a forced line break with `.3\baselineskip`. So it may look a bit like a vertical space of `1.3\baselineskip` but it will behave very strangely at a page break. If a page breaks before the paragraph, the blank line will not be dropped at the start of a page, as vertical space would be. If a page break happens after the blank line, you will have a blank line at the bottom of on page then the `.3\baselineskip` space will be dropped at the start of the next.

Comment: Would the cleanest and understandable solution then consist of using `\color`?  With your changes, we could then avoid using `\vspace` or `\blskip`.

Comment: I have noticed that when I change the document setting to use a bold typeface, the text following the theorem number `\begin{theore}[Convolution]` does not inherit the bold typeface?  One might consider it a bug.

Comment: you (I guess?) incorrectly posted such a bug to the latex bug tracker, I don't see why you would consider it a bug?

Comment: What would be your suggested solution if is not a bug?  I would argue some enhancements if you don't mind hearing.  Or perhaps the solutions are already built-in and need only to use them.

Comment: What I wanted to have was a bold typeface throughout, with the theorem string and theorem number in colour.

Comment: That is an unrelated question to this one though (which is about vertical space)

Comment: Would you help explain why I get `LaTeX Error: Command \theorem already defined.                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` when using your solution?

Comment: @Ephram I copy and pasted @David's answer and do not get the error message you have, can you explain the steps you took to get the error? Did you copy and paste bits of the answer into your own main document? The error says that you have defined `\theorem` already so perhaps you kept your original definition and copied this answers definition in too and have 2 definitions, delete one of them perhaps and check back into us

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor You were correct.  I had `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` again after that to use the section numbering.  So I included `[section]` to David's definition.