# Highlight table cells using thick, colored border

Tags: tables, rules, highlighting, colortbl

I'd like to highlight certain cells of my table. In particular, I'd like to set the border of these sells colored and thick. These cells should also have a background color.

Here's a minimal example of my table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,colortbl,xcolor}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tabular}{p{1.4cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Football}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Basketball}} \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Average} & 10000000000 & \cellcolor{lightgray}20000000000 & 30000000000 & 40000000000\\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & 50000000000 & 60000000000 & 70000000000 & \cellcolor{lightgray}80000000000\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I tried to set the border of specific cells using a combination of multicolumn and hhline but failed miserably :-( (One of the problems was that the cell background partially covers the border).

I also tried [tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/highlighting-table-cells) but failed to paint exactly on the cell's border, especially when a linebreak occurs.

Here's how it should look optimally:

[image]

Can someone please help me to get this working?

Answer (score 12):

[image]

I have prevented the cell from becoming wider due to the border, but allowed it to grow vertically. If that isn't desired a bit more negative spacing is needed.

rather than use `colortbl` it is easier to grab the cell contents in a box (since you are doing that anyway for `p` columns) and using `\fcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,colortbl,xcolor}

\begin{document} 

\makeatletter
\def\highlight#1{%
\fboxrule2pt %
\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax
#1%
\@endpbox\unskip\setbox0\lastbox\bgroup
\fboxrule2pt %
\fcolorbox{red}{lightgray}{\box0}\hfill}

\begin{tabular}{p{1.4cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Football}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Basketball}} \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Average} & 10000000000 & \cellcolor{lightgray}20000000000 & 30000000000 & 40000000000\\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & 50000000000 & 60000000000 &
\highlight{70000000000}& \cellcolor{lightgray}80000000000\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this nice solution! I still have a minor request for improvement: Is it possible, that the red box takes the whole space of the cell, i.e. that it has contact with the left and right cell? In the current solution there is a small white space.

Comment: I think you are just seeing the tabcolsep space between columns in a tabular if you suppress that with `p{2.55cm}@{}p{2.55cm}` where the `@{}` suppresses all inter-column material, two adjacent `\highlight` entries touch when I try it.

Comment: How would you vertically fit the bordered fbox exactly in the cell? In your example, the bordered cells are higher than regular cells.

Answer (score 5):

I provide a solution with TikZ and the now famous `\tikzmark` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% to change colors
\newcommand{\fillcol}{blue!20}
\newcommand{\bordercol}{blue}

\newcommand{\setfillcolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\fillcol}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setbordercolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\bordercol}{#1}}

%% code by Andrew Stacey 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/background-coloring-with-overlay-specification-in-algorithm2e-beamer-package#51582

\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
     remember picture with id/.style={%
       remember picture,
       overlay,
       save picture id=#1,
     },
     save picture id/.code={%
       \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
       \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
         \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
     },
     if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
       \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
         \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
       }{
         \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
       }
     }
   }

   \def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzmarkin}{m D(){0.825,-0.10} D(){-0.175,0.27}}{%
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw[line width=1pt,rectangle,fill=\fillcol,draw=\bordercol]
      (pic cs:#1) ++(#2) rectangle (#3)
      ;}

\newcommand\tikzmarkend[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}


\begin{document} 
\setfillcolor{lightgray}
\setbordercolor{red}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.4cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Football}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Basketball}} \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Average} & \tikzmarkin{d}(0.1,-0.1)(-0.1,0.27)10000000000\tikzmarkend{d} & \tikzmarkin{b}20000000000\tikzmarkend{b} & 30000000000 & 40000000000\\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & 50000000000 & 60000000000 & \tikzmarkin{c}70000000000\tikzmarkend{c} & \tikzmarkin{a}80000000000\tikzmarkend{a}\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The default setting allows to get the so called *optimal look*, but it is also possible to shorten the highlighting box. This is why the `\tikzmark` version adopted is taken from [Issues and potentiality of the tikzmark macro: dynamic box adaptation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/issues-and-potentiality-of-the-tikzmark-macro-dynamic-box-adaptation#57655) and uses *extendible* markers. An example is given in the above code:

```
\tikzmarkin{d}(0.1,-0.1)(-0.1,0.27)10000000000\tikzmarkend{d}
```

where `(0.1,-0.1)` represent the `end` shift marker and `(-0.1,0.27)` the `in` shift marker.

The solution leads to:

[image]

This approach requires the document to be compiled twice and even allows to get something like:

[image]

```
\begin{document} 
\setfillcolor{lightgray}
\setbordercolor{red}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.4cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Football}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Basketball}} \\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Average} & \tikzmarkin{d}(0.1,-0.1)(-0.1,0.27)10000000000 & \tikzmarkin{b}20000000000\tikzmarkend{b} & 30000000000 & 40000000000\\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & 50000000000\tikzmarkend{d} & 60000000000 & \tikzmarkin{c}70000000000\tikzmarkend{c} & \tikzmarkin{a}80000000000\tikzmarkend{a}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks complicated for beginners, but works like a charm. Especially the boxes across multiple cells are neat.

Comment: @Klaster: Glad it helps. Yes, I think this solution can give a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't run David Carlisle's the last solution, perhaps due to changes in the `array` package (using v2.4l).

I'm not fluent in TeX to correct the definition of `highlight`, so I wrote a new command `highlighti` which seems to get the same result.

I also changed the column specs from `p` to `w` to have better number alignment, and added a stretch to the rows to make more room for the edges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,colortbl,xcolor}

\begin{document} 

%   \makeatletter
%   \def\highlight#1{%
%       \fboxrule2pt %
%       \hsize=\dimexpr\hsize-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax
%       #1%
%       \@endpbox\unskip\setbox0\lastbox\bgroup
%       \fboxrule2pt %
%       \fcolorbox{red}{lightgray}{\box0}\hfill}

\newcommand{\highlighti}[2]{%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
    \fcolorbox{#1}{lightgray}{#2}}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7} %make room for borders
    
%\begin{tabular}{p{1.4cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}w{c}{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.4cm}w{c}{2.55cm}w{c}{2.55cm}w{c}{2.55cm}w{c}{2.55cm}}   % changed for better alignment
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Football}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Basketball}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1. League}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2. League}} \\
     \hline
    \textbf{Average} & 10000000000 & \highlighti{white}{20000000000} & 30000000000 & \highlighti{white}{40000000000}\\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{Total} & 50000000000 & 60000000000 &
    \highlighti{red}{70000000000}
     & \highlighti{white}{80000000000}\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1.4cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}}[hlines]
& \Block{1-2}{\textbf{Football}} && \Block{1-2}{\textbf{Basketball}} \\
& \Block{}{\textbf{1. League}} & \Block{}{\textbf{2. League}} & \Block{}{\textbf{1. League}} & \Block{}{\textbf{2. League}} \\ 
\textbf{Average} & 10000000000 &\Block[l,fill=lightgray,draw=red,line-width=1.2pt]{}{20000000000} & 30000000000 & 40000000000\\ 
\textbf{Total} & 50000000000 & 60000000000 & 70000000000 &\Block[l,fill=lightgray,draw=red,line-width=1.2pt]{}{80000000000}\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the first code]

If you want the red lines completely inside the cells, it's also possible (≥ 6.24):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand{\MyBlock}{\Block[l,tikz={offset=0.6pt,fill=lightgray,draw=red,line width=1.2pt}]}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{1.4cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}p{2.55cm}}[hlines,color-inside]
& \Block{1-2}{\textbf{Football}} && \Block{1-2}{\textbf{Basketball}} \\
& \Block{}{\textbf{1. League}} & \Block{}{\textbf{2. League}} & \Block{}{\textbf{1. League}} & \Block{}{\textbf{2. League}} \\ 
\textbf{Average} & 10000000000 & \MyBlock{}{20000000000} & 30000000000 & 40000000000\\ 
\textbf{Total} & 50000000000 & 60000000000 & 70000000000 &\MyBlock{}{80000000000}\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]