How to use bold horizontal and vertical lines in a specific row of table?
I need a Table as shown in the attached image file. Could you help me to generate this table according to the image file. Thank you in advance.

\documentclass[]{article}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{caption}   \label{tab:1}%
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
        \hline
        A     & B \\
        \hline
        X     & 10 \\
        \hline
        Y     & 20 \\
        \hline
        Z     & 30 \\
        \hline
        P     & 33 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}


Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4676/277964, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416498/277964

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{caption}   \label{tab:1}%
    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}[hvlines]
        A     & B \\
        X     & 10 \\
        Y     & 20 \\
        Z     & 30 \\
    \Block[l,draw,line-width=1pt]{}{P}
&   \Block[l,draw,line-width=1pt]{}{33}
    \end{NiceTabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}


