# How to mark/round an element of a table/tabular?

Tags: tables, pstricks

I´m creating a table for simplex, and I want to create a circle around a number in a table.

How can I make this in LaTeX?

I use PSTricks, but I prefer don´t create an image and a table/tabular inside that image.

I don´t know if in PSTricks, I can create a circle anywhere in the page or only in the rectangle in `\psspicture (lower left)(upper right)`.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/highlighting-table-cells help?

Comment: Perhaps [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/13304) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, a number for you is not

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939
9375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825
3421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822
3172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964
4622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648
2337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543
266482133936072602491412737245870066063,
```

but rather 1, 2, 3, ...

Then one of solutions is a `pifont` package, where circled numbers are obtained  by `\ding{172}--\ding{181}`, `\ding{182}--\ding{191}`, `\ding{192}--\ding{201}`, and `\ding{202}--\ding{211}`.

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly, it's a table for simplex algorithm, so what happens if the OP needs `13`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Hence I am waiting for a clarification, what numbers OP has in mind. And if a circle with number 13 should be the same as the one with number 1.

Comment: Yes, I think in numbers like 1,2,3....  or 1.23 , 1.89, 10.34 ,...  or  1.234, 5,654, 15.356.....  or 1+1/2 ,   12+34/21,...

Comment: @MikaIke So dingbats are useless. But pretty! What about radii for different numbers?

Comment: I think that the radius should be diferent in order to the extension of the number.