# high resolution table of numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, pstricks, posters

I'd like to design a table of numbers for poster-size printing, say like a multiplication table, so I'm looking for: high resolution, colors, pretty fonts.

Does it sound like it could be done in LaTeX or related languages?

I'm reasonably proficient in PSTricks, I have never used TikZ but am happy to learn.

Edit: Here are a couple of examples of fonts I have come across:

http://www.dafont.com/kg-traditional-fractions.font

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/MEgalopolis-Extra

How would you proceed to include these fonts in a LaTeX document?

Comment: If you are using scalable fonts (almost all these days) resolution is not an issue is it? You could do it in latex but you may need to give a better idea of what "it" is, clearly you could make a poster of table of numbers with just base latex and no packages, so you probably need to give some idea of the kind of decoration you have in mind.

Comment: Thanks David, sorry my question is incredibly vague. Well, I know how to do things like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119668/how-to-mark-round-an-element-of-a-table-tabular,   but I'd like to go a few steps towards:    http://www.zazzle.com/fun_colorful_multiplication_table_poster-228313329025446300, fancy colours, some sort of 3-D feel...

Comment: It's of course your choice, but the table you are linking to not at all reader friendly. `:(`

Comment: I'm with @SvendTveskæg, a poster should transmit information in a friendly way, should be readable. That poster it's the exact opposite.

Comment: Sorry, I intended to show an example of fancy fonts (my question is about pretty, colourful fonts): like some sort of 3-D effect, glossy colours, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

download the fonts and save it into your fonts folder or the documents one

Then run this example with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\TFrac[Scale=2]{KGTraditionalFractions}
\newfontface\TFracTwo[Scale=2]{KGTraditionalFractions2}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

{\TFrac    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\
           abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

{\TFracTwo ?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\
             abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\char099\char100\char101}

\end{document}
```

[image]