# draw circle around cells in table and use pause for this cells

Tags: beamer

I am trying to draw circles on two cells on Latex beamer  then use `\pause` to mention that.
 here an example which I want to draw a circle around `AA` and `BB`, the mentions shows that `BB` first then `AA`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\begin{tabular}{|ccccccc|}
\hline
AA&
B&
C&
BB&
A&
B&
C\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

May give me a hand, please?

Comment: does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4861/36296 help?

Comment: I have seen it but I did not manage to add '\pause' to them.

Comment: Can you draw a sketch, what should be on the first slide etc? At the moment I find it a bit unclear. Should all the cells be there and only the circle added? Or should the cells be overlayed? Instead of `\pause`, I would rather use `\only<>{}`, see the beameruserguide.pdf for detailed explanation.

Comment: You can use `tikzmark` (which is a package/library providing functions similar to the code in the answer @samcarter linked). But `\onslide` or `\only` or similar is definitely the way to go here rather than `\pause` which is too crude for this. (I'm not sure what you want exactly either, but I'm sure `\pause` will be too crude.)

Answer (score 3):

I am still not sure what exactly you mean by "`\pause` to mention that", so I just guess, that you want the circles to appear stepwise.

Based on [Highlighting table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/highlighting-table-cells/4861#4861)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\newcounter{nodemarkers}
\newcommand<>\circletext[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a) at (0,1.5ex) {};%
    #1%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b) at (0,0){};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=2pt]
    \node#2[draw,ellipse,fit=(marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a.center) (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b.center)] {};%
    \stepcounter{nodemarkers}%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{test}

        \begin{tabular}{|ccccccc|}
            \hline
            \circletext<2->{AA}&
            B&
            C&
            \circletext<3>{BB}&
            A&
            B&
            C\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]