# draw circles around cells in a table (followup)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

The example below is a slightly modified version of the answer in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311367/draw-circle-around-cells-in-table-and-use-pause-for-this-cells).    I want to condition the circles on whether or not I'm running in `desktop` or `presentation` mode.     How would I define the counters `aCirc` and `bCirc` so that in `desktop` mode no circles appear?       In `presentation` mode I can kill off one or other circles by setting the appropriate counter to 0.    But for some reason, that doesn't work for `desktop` mode.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\newcounter{nodemarkers}
\newcommand<>\circletext[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a) at (0,1.5ex) {};%
    #1%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b) at (0,0){};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=2pt]
    \node#2[draw,ellipse,fit=(marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a.center) (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b.center)] {};%
    \stepcounter{nodemarkers}%
}

\newcounter{aCirc}
\newcounter{bCirc}
\setcounter{aCirc}{2}
\setcounter{bCirc}{3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[<+->]
        \frametitle{test}

        \begin{tabular}{|ccccccc|}
            \hline
            \circletext<\theaCirc>{AAAAA}&
            B&
            C&
            \circletext<\thebCirc>{BB}&
            A&
            B&
            C\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "desktop"?

Comment: I'm using either `\documentclass[desktop]{beamer}` or `documentclass{beamer}`.    I can get the result I want when I use the latter, but when I add the `[desktop]` option, I can't selectively pick my circles.

Comment: You can use `\@ifclasswith{beamer}{desktop}{}{}` to test the documentclass option: `\makeatletter`
    `\@ifclasswith{beamer}{desktop}{
        Define \circletext for desktop mode
    }{
        Define \circletext for other mode
    }`
`\makeatother`

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is this option supposed to do?

Comment: I learned about it from @Mike.   It's invaluable.    With `desktop` mode, you create one slide per frame, i.e., all overlays are suppressed, so a presentation with hundreds of slides is reduced to one with a manageable number.     This is what one wants for everything *except* giving actual presentations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use `\@ifclasswith{beamer}{desktop}{}{}` to detect the package option and then define a TikZ style:

```
\makeatletter
    \@ifclasswith{beamer}{desktop}{
        \tikzset{my ellipse style/.style={draw=none}}
    }{
        \tikzset{my ellipse style/.style={draw, ellipse}}
    }
\makeatother
```

### Notes:

- I am not a beamer expert so not sure why I needed a `\RequirePackage{tikz}` to have the `\tikzset` macro availalable

### Code:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}% Need to get \tikzset for some reason
\documentclass[desktop]{beamer}

\makeatletter
    \@ifclasswith{beamer}{desktop}{
        \tikzset{my ellipse style/.style={draw=none}}
    }{
        \tikzset{my ellipse style/.style={draw, ellipse}}
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand<>\circletext[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a) at (0,1.5ex) {};%
    #1%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
    \node (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b) at (0,0){};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=2pt]
    \node#2[my ellipse style,fit=(marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-a.center) 
        (marker-\arabic{nodemarkers}-b.center)] {};%
    \stepcounter{nodemarkers}%
}%


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\newcounter{nodemarkers}

\newcounter{aCirc}
\newcounter{bCirc}
\setcounter{aCirc}{2}
\setcounter{bCirc}{3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[<+->]
        \frametitle{test}

        \begin{tabular}{|ccccccc|}
            \hline
            \circletext<\theaCirc>{AAAAA}&
            B&
            C&
            \circletext<\thebCirc>{BB}&
            A&
            B&
            C\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, @PeterGrill.    I should have been clearer in my original question.     I'm calling the same piece of code repeatedly.    In one frame I want just  `AAAAA` circled, in another I want just `BB` circled.  In `presentation` mode this is easy to accomplish, but in `desktop` not so easy.    Your suggestion turns off circling completely in `desktop` mode.    Is there some way to avoid this?     Thanks!

Comment: @LeoSimon: Just use `\@ifclasswith{beamer}{desktop}{}{}` to define the appropriate conditionals. I don't fully understand your requirement so am hesitant to change the code.

Comment: Thanks @PeterGrill.   ultimately I didn't use `@ifclasswith`.   Instead I used your `\tikzset` options, but added an additional argument to the  defintion of `\circletext`, and within that macro, conditioned the choice of your two `\tikzset` commands on whether or not the new argument was zero.    This way I could accomplish in `desktop` mode exactly the functionality provided in `presentation` mode.    It's clumsy, but works and gives me the flexibility I need