# circle table cell in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I want to circle the cell as shown in image. How do I do this inside a beamer frame?

I followed [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311367/draw-circle-around-cells-in-table-and-use-pause-for-this-cells) but couldn't figure out how to make the circle bold and red.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c | c }
            Competitor Name & Swim & Cycle & Run & Total \\
            \hline \hline
            John T & 13:04 & 24:15 & 18:34 & 55:53 \\ 
            Norman P & 8:00 & 22:45 & 23:02 & 53:47\\
            Alex K & 14:00 & 28:00 & n/a & n/a\\
            Sarah H & 9:22 & 21:10 & 24:03 & 54:35 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Triathlon results}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compileable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tikz` as described in [this answer to "How to add arrow in equations and matrix?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361392/110998):

- Define `\tikznode` in the preamble.
- Assign a label to the text that you want to decorate using `\tikznode`.
- Add a `tikzpicture` environment with the decoration (using the label from the last step).
- Don't forget to run LaTeX at least twice to get the positions right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\tikznode[3][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#2.base)]
    \node[minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,#1](#2){#3};%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c | c }
    Competitor Name & Swim & Cycle & Run & Total \\
    \hline\hline
    John T & 13:04 & 24:15 & 18:34 & 55:53 \\ 
    Norman P & 8:00 & 22:45 & 23:02 & 53:47\\
    Alex K & 14:00 & \tikznode{alex}{28:00} & n/a & n/a\\
    Sarah H & 9:22 & 21:10 & 24:03 & 54:35 
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[red,very thick] (alex) circle[x radius=8mm,y radius=4mm]; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A follow up question - how do i  use `\onslide` with this? i.e the red circle will appear after  a pause

Comment: okay figured it out. just needed to add `\onslide<2->` before `begin{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `tikzmark` library. Based on [highlight cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489942/beamer-shading-columns-and-highlight-extra/489966):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,             
                tikzmark,       % <---
                shapes.geometric}  
\tikzset{FIT/.style = {%
    ellipse, draw=red, thick, inner xsep=0pt, fit=#1}
        }
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Use of \texttt{tikzmark} library}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c | c }
Competitor Name
            & Swim  & Cycle                     & Run   & Total \\
    \hhline{=:=:=:=:=}
John T      & 13:04 & 24:15                     & 18:34 & 55:53 \\
Norman P    & 8:00  & 22:45                     & 23:02 & 53:47 \\
Alex K      & 14:00 & \tikzmarknode{a}{28:00}   & n/a   & n/a   \\
Sarah H     & 9:22  & 21:10                     & 24:03 & 54:35
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[FIT=(a)] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Table}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the ellipsis.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}  
\tikzset{FIT/.style = {ellipse, draw=red, thick, inner xsep=0pt, fit=#1} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Use of the \texttt{nicematrix}}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{l | c | c | c | c }
Competitor Name
            & Swim  & Cycle   & Run   & Total \\
\Hline\Hline
John T      & 13:04 & 24:15   & 18:34 & 55:53 \\
Norman P    & 8:00  & 22:45   & 23:02 & 53:47 \\
Alex K      & 14:00 & 28:00   & n/a   & n/a   \\
Sarah H     & 9:22  & 21:10   & 24:03 & 54:35 \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \node[FIT=(4-3)] {} ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Table}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

As I don't know what the `\h` command is, I replaced it with a couple of`\hline`s. You can circle a cell contents with the `circledsteps` package:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}

\begin{table}
\color{NavyBlue}
\begin{tabular}{l | c | c | c | c }
Competitor Name & Swim & Cycle & Run & Total \\
\hline\hline
John T & 13:04 & 24:15 & 18:34 & 55:53 \\
Norman P & \phantom{0}8:00 & 22:45 & 23:02 & 53:47\\
Alex K & 14:00 & \Circled[outer color=IndianRed, inner ysep=8pt]{28:00} & n/a & n/a\\
Sarah H & \phantom{0}9:22 & 21:10 & 24:03 & 54:35
\end{tabular}
\caption{Triathlon results}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]